# How do I replace an NIS master server?

Tags: linux, nis

I need to take down my current NIS master server because it is running on RHEL 4 which is too old for the auditors to approve now.

I think I need to copy some files off the master over to a slave server and run make?

I know there are files listed in the makefile but which ones are necessary for this and which ones should be left alone?

The slave server is running Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Nis is also really old fashioned. Why not join us in the 21st century and use ldap instead?

Comment: @DennisKaarsemaker has a point - particularly if your concern is site audits, LDAP is superior to NIS in most respects. For now [grs' outline below should get you migrated to a modern OS](http://serverfault.com/a/503369/32986), but Long-Term you should be looking to migrate off of NIS...

Comment: LOL that is the goal. I had to get the current NIS down quick and just need this in a VM while i get LDAP up. Most likely my next question on here will be a good script to migrate the users over. Or if one exists anyway. This is for a university. A place where you'll find NIS :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Let's assume that the domain configuration is under `/var/yp/<domainname>`;
2. Let's assume the NIS server configuration is under `/var/yp`;
3. Let's assume you have some NIS related configuration files under `/etc/` as well. Those could be `/etc/yp.conf`, `/etc/ypserv.conf`, `/etc/ypserv.securenets` and possible others (their filenames usually begin with `yp...`.

What you need to do in order to move your NIS to the new server:

1. **Copy all of these files from the old server to the new one.** 
   Make sure they are not existent there beforehand or if they are - take backups before overwriting them!
2. **Decide if the new server will have the same hostname and IP address as the original master.**
   If the name is the same you would skip the clients reconfiguration, otherwise it will be necessary to point to the right server (host or IP). I would rather reconfigure the clients
3. **Copy the passwords, groups, shadow files from the old server to the new one**
4. **Once you have all files on the new server, run `make -C /var/yp`**
   You may need to stop the NIS service on the old server, as the domains are to be the same and can't have two master servers. If no errors - continue with following steps. Otherwise - well ... troubleshoot.
5. **Run `ypwhich` on the new server and verify it returns its own hostname**
6. **Run `ypcat passwd | grep <username>`, `ypcat group | grep <groupname>`**
   Verify this works as expected;
7. **Stop the NIS service on the old server, if not done earlier**
8. **Reconfigure all NIS clients**
   Change their `/etc/yp.conf` to point to the respective server:
   `echo -e "ypserver new_NIS_server" >> /etc/yp.conf`.
   (alternatively this is where you would give the new machine the old one's IP/Hostname).

Good luck!

Comment: That's pretty comprehensive.  Note that if you're one of the few places that's still using broadcast to determine NIS servers you might not need to do step 8.